# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, hbase

When I start-hbase.sh

HMaster and HregionServer are coming up but not visible after some time.

By looking at logs I found this.

**HMaster:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: 
class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3150)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3164)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "//localhost" caused by empty node name specified @1
at org.apache.zookeeper.common.PathUtils.validatePath(PathUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.(ConnectStringParser.java:57)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:443)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.checkZk(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.createNonSequential(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:575)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.create(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:554)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createWithParents(ZKUtil.java:1207)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createWithParents(ZKUtil.java:1185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.createBaseZNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.(HMaster.java:561)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3145)
... 5 more
```

**HRegionServer:**

```
2017-02-16 00:34:51,541 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server centos64,60020,1487185489375:     Initialization of RS failed. Hence aborting RS.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "//localhost" caused by empty node name specified @1
at org.apache.zookeeper.common.PathUtils.validatePath(PathUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.(ConnectStringParser.java:57)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:443)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.checkZk(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:363)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:784)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:757)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:889)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2017-02-16 00:34:51,554 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2017-02-16 00:34:51,559 INFO [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer:  STOPPED: Initialization of RS failed. Hence aborting RS.
2017-02-16 00:34:51,559 INFO [regionserver60020] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60020
2017-02-16 00:34:51,559 INFO [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Stopping infoServer
2017-02-16 00:34:51,609 INFO [regionserver60020] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60030
2017-02-16 00:34:51,813 INFO [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: aborting server null
2017-02-16 00:34:51,832 INFO [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server null; all regions closed.
2017-02-16 00:34:51,833 INFO [regionserver60020] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:   Initiating client connection, connectString=hdfs://localhost   sessionTimeout=90000   watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@336f0152
2017-02-16 00:34:52,911 INFO [main] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Installed   shutdown hook thread: Shutdownhook:regionserver60020
2017-02-16 00:34:52,914 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine:   Region server exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HRegionServer Aborted
at  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2594)
2017-02-16 00:34:52,922 INFO [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true; fsShutdownHook=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$ClientFinalizer@6424c070
2017-02-16 00:34:52,925 INFO [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Starting  fs shutdown hook thread.
2017-02-16 00:34:52,936 INFO [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook finished.
```

**My Hbase-site.xml:**

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost</value>
 </property>

 </configuration>
```

**My core-site.xml**

```
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://CentOS64:9000</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/root/hadoop/tmp</value>
   </property>


 </configuration>
```

My Hosts:

192.168.79.10 CentOS64 localhost

I tried with CentOS64, and by giving ip also, still same issue.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` accepts

> Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.

Change the value of property and restart the Hbase services,

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
 </property>
```

From your other configuration properties, the setup looks like Pseudo Distributed, for local and pseudo-distributed modes of operation this is set to `localhost` by default. You can omit this property from `hbase-site.xml` for these modes.

Else, add the complete list of Zookeeper servers as comma seperated servers to this property.